# python data analysis overlay image of US

Tags: javascript, python

I am familiar with coding in python for the work I do in bioinformatics. I've recently been asked to do a different type of analysis -- analyzing data and then overlaying that data over a map of the US. I figure I will need to use javascript after I write the python code to do the data analysis, but I am not familiar with creating images. What is the best way to incorporate my python data analysis with code that will produce a dynamic image?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've seen some amazing map overlays using [D3](http://d3js.org/)

Comment: You can also use the [Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solutions**

1) Just as what what other people said , you could try to use the Google Map APIs and code a bit.

2) Or you can use Openstreetmap. I would perfer openstreetmap.

I did several apps and websites based on LBS. I know how to place coordinates on maps.

If you want to finish this quickly and cooler. You may try this combination:

`Django as the freamwork,
PostgreSQL as the DB backend
PostgreSQL PGIS as the geolocation handler
Openstreetmap as the map viewer`

**My summery:**

Solution 1) is quick, faster. It needs you some hard-coding efforts.

Solution 2) is bit slower but full-featured. It's very extensive for future developing.

Hope this could help you